# Line graph using Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to plot a graph like in attached image ,using tableua by getting data from a text file .

It is having 3 fields Datetime ,track ,inuse

We have 43 different track sizes.Need to plot graph for each track with all in a single graph.
Please help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be easy to do in tableau. Try putting time on columns, "inuse" on rows and "track" on color.

I do not have your data but am using the data that tableau desktop ships with. Here is what it looks like with the superstore demo data:

[image]

To display the labels, also place track on the label shelf. If you then click on the label shelf, you can choose options about where to display them. To mimic your example, label the line ends.